# Why SQL code isn't running?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website which asks input from user using this html code:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="question1input1" />
</form>
```

But when I ran it on the second page using this php to upload into database:

```
$que1in1 = $_POST['question1input1'];

if ($que1in1 == "x-coordinate") {

    $answer = '<text style=\'color: yellowgreen;\'>x-coordinate</text>';

    $score = 1;

    $snumber = $_SESSION['DcYnuJmQKJkkBPEY'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE `chapter 9 pre-test` SET `score1` = '$score' WHERE `chapter 9 pre-test`.`snumber`='$snumber';";

    $sql3 = "UPDATE `chapter 9 pre-test` SET `1` = '".$answer."' WHERE `chapter 9 pre-test`.`snumber`='$snumber';";

    if ($con->query($sql2) == TRUE) {}

    else {echo "something happened... ".$score;}

    if ($con->query($sql3) == TRUE) {}

    else {echo "something happened... ".$answer;}

}
```

`$sql2` returning as success, but `$sql3` returning as an error.

Comment: Can you have spaces in table names?

Comment: Try changing the column name, not just a number, maybe `answer1`.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If only there was something that recorded errors, like in a file, then you could go and look at it.

Comment: Your column name is `1`? Or it is a typo?

Comment: Print the database error message when an error happens. `echo $con->error;`.

Comment: So many things wrong with this code, where to begin...

Comment: This `$answer = '<text style=\'color: yellowgreen;\'>x-coordinate</text>';` needs to be double escaped because the first escaping is for the PHP. Parameterize your queries and you won't have this issue. Also please rename your tables and columns.

Comment: It is not the first time I use 1 as the table name and it was always worked fine + I tried it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

try changing your html code in `$answer` to use double quote since you are using single quote as a string delimiter in your update query

```
$answer = '<text style="color: yellowgreen;">x-coordinate</text>';
```

and if this is the cause of this problem, I suggest you use PDO and prepared statements instead. this will not happen if you are using prepared statements